# Is there an online/standalone Computer Simulator / Demo program?

Tags: memory, heap-memory, execution, stack-memory, turing-machines

I would like to be able to give students an awareness of *exactly* what happens during program execution inside a modern computer - e.g. use of memory addresses, references, stack, heap and so on.

Ideally I'd like for them to be able to play with some kind of demo where a simple application (e.g. calculator, rudimentary database etc.) runs and can be paused and the state of the machine running the program viewed at quite a low level via a 'pretty' GUI.

Does such an application exist? And if not, could any super-coders advise on the feasibility of writing a piece of software like this? The target audience are probably 1st year Comp Sci students learning a modern OO language (C#, Java ideally).

EDIT:

*I thought this had gone cold but someone posted today so I thought I'd better update...*

I should probably have put the words 'Turing' and 'machine' into this question. I think people thought I wanted to debug Windows or something when actually I was just thinking of TMs. [This is a pretty good simulator](http://ironphoenix.org/tril/tm/), though not pretty by today's standards.

If anyone knows of any others, I'd appreciate you posting a link. Thanks.

Comment: Don't know whether it exists yet, but as for feasibility, it seems that you would essentially have to write a compiler, which could take a long time.

Comment: There are plenty of computer "simulator" and "inspector" programs around, but I don't think they will answer your question.
If you want to honestly simulate a computer, there are virtualization software like VMware, Bochs, QEMU, etc.
If you want to examine the instructions that an application executes, you can use a debugger like gdb.
In either case, the problem is that you will be overwhelmed by the number of instructions it takes to do anything meaningful.

Comment: I was wondering if it would be possible to do something at the application-code level and was considering the use of reflection in Java and C# to drive a visual representation of the classes and data exchange. I'd appreciate your thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

I've been googling around for the same sort of thing (ability to see the heap and stack in real time) and came across this:

http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit